# Proving $\lim x^n = a^n$ as $x$ goes to $a$ from definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, epsilon-delta

> Using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition show that
>   $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} x^n = a^n$

What I've done? Pretty much stuck on the step where one usually constructs delta:

$\displaystyle |x^n-a^n| < \varepsilon \implies \bigg|x-a\bigg|\bigg|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k a^{n-k-1}\bigg| <\varepsilon \implies |x-a| < \frac{\epsilon}{ \bigg| \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k a^{n-k-1}\bigg|}$.

At this stage I cannot bound the denominator. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: As $x\to a,x^k\cdot a^{n-k-1}=?$

Comment: @abiessu Don't I need exactly what I'm trying to prove to show that it's $a^{n-1}$?

Comment: @user276387 do you know how to do it for $n=2$?

Comment: @AhmedHussein Yes, I do.

Comment: Let $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $\delta = \min(\frac{\varepsilon}{2|a|+1}, 1)$. Suppose $x \in\mathbb{R} - \left\{a\right\} $ and $|x-a| < \delta.$ Then $|x-a| < 1$ hence $ -1 < x-a <1 $ hence $ a-1 < x < a+1$ therefore $2a-1< x+a <2a+1.$ Thus $ |x+a| < 2|a|+1.$ So $|x^2-a^2| = |x-a||x+a|$ $ \displaystyle < (2|a|+1)\delta =(2|a|+1)\frac{\varepsilon}{(2|a|+1)} = \varepsilon. $

Comment: Do you see how a similar argument can be done here?

Comment: @AhmedHussein I'm unable to :[ With the other one I was just bounding |x+a| - I'm not sure how to extend it to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have:

$$\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{\text{something}} < \frac{\epsilon}{|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k a^{n-k-1}|}$$

Then, $\text{something}$ must be greater than $|\sum x^k a^{n-k-1}|$. If we choose $\delta < 1$, then we would have for $|x - a| < \delta < 1$, $|x| < 1 + |a|$.

$$|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k a^{n-k-1}| \le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|x|^k |a|^{n-k-1} < \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1 + |a|)^k |a|^{n-k-1} < \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1+|a|)^k (1+|a|)^{n-k-1} \le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1+|a|)^{n-1} = n(1 +|a|)^{n-1}$$

Thus, choosing:

$$\delta = \min\{1, \frac{\epsilon}{n(1+|a|)^{n-1}}\}$$

does the job.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!